# Springdoc OpenAPI 3.0 Swagger - GroupedOpenApi not working in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.14

I have following class

```
@Configuration
public class GroupsConfig {

    private final PropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    public GroupsConfig(PropertyResolver propertyResolver) {
        this.propertyResolver = propertyResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi adminApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("admin")
                .pathsToMatch("/admin/**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi externalApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("external")
                .pathsToMatch("/external/**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi clientApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("client")
                .pathsToMatch("/client/**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi externalClientApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("extclient")
                .pathsToMatch("/extclient/**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI apiInfo() {
        String title = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_TITLE);
        String description = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_DESCRIPTION);
        String version = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_VERSION);
        String contactName = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_CONTACT_NAME);
        String contactUrl = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_CONTACT_URL);
        String contactEmail = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_CONTACT_EMAIL);
        String termsOfServiceUrl = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_TERMS_OF_SERVICE_URL);
        String licence = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_LICENCE);
        String licenceUrl = propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(SwaggerPropertyKey.API_LICENCE_URL);

        Contact contact = new Contact()
                .name(contactName)
                .url(contactUrl)
                .email(contactEmail);

        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title(title)
                        .description(description)
                        .version(version)
                        .license(new License().name(licence).url(licenceUrl))
                        .contact(contact)
                        .termsOfService(termsOfServiceUrl))
                .components(new Components());
    }
}
```

**The *OpenAPI* info is working correctly and displayed in the UI.**

I then have follewing class to import all Springdoc configurations manually

```
@Configuration
@Import({org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties.class,
        org.springdoc.webmvc.core.MultipleOpenApiSupportConfiguration.class,
        org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class, org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
        SwaggerUiConfigParameters.class, SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
        org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
        org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class, GroupsConfig.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SwaggerConfig {
}
```

If I go to /v3/api-docs, I get a giant JSON with all the different paths in my application. If I go to /v3/api-docs/admin, I get a 404. So the GroupedOpenApi beans are not getting picked up by Springdoc.

Anyone having the same issue or an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I just tried it with 1.4.4 and it works. What should I do to get it working with the newest version?